# PHP loop hanging/interspersed/threaded through HTML

Tags: php, html, loops

I can't figure out how to say what I'm talking about which is a big part of why I'm stuck. In PHP I often see code like this

```
html
<?php
   language construct that uses brackets {
       some code;
?>
more html
<?php
       some more code;
    }
?>
rest of html
```

Is there any name for this? Having seen this lead me to try it out so here is a concrete example whose behavior doesn't make sense to me

```
<div id="content">
<ul id="nav">
<?php
    $path = 'content';
    $dir = dir($path);
    while(false !== ($file = $dir->read())) {
        if(preg_match('/.+\.txt/i', $file)) {
            echo "<li class=\"$file\">$file</li>";
?>
</ul>
<?php
            echo "<p class=\"$file\">" . file_get_contents($path . '/' . $file) . '</p>';
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

Which outputs roughly `<div><ul><li></li></ul><li></li><p></p>...</div>` instead of `<div><ul><li></li>...</ul><p></p>...</div>`, which is what I thought would happen and what I want to happen. To make it clearer I want the `<li>` inside the `<ul>` and the `<p>` inside the `<div>`. Yes, I know there is an easy solution but I was wondering if there is a way to do it with the technique I am looking for a name for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just something to add here:

If you're using a PHP loop for templating, there is another syntax that helps you avoid confusion with indentation and which-braces-match-which:

```
<?php
    foreach($items as $item):
?>
<b>item: </b> <?php echo $item; ?> <br />
<?php
    endforeach;
?>
```

this may be an oversimplification, but really you shouldn't be using anything more complicated than this in a template. Things like the `$items` variable and anything else you need should be set up by the code which includes the template, and not in the template itself.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the alternative syntax that is made for templating.

Comment: That makes it entirely clear how to do what I was thinking, I should have the loop surrounding the div instead of inside of it. Still I hope I can get an explanation for how whatever I'm trying to talk about works.

Comment: how it works? You mean putting HTML between PHP blocks?
When a PHP file is sent by a webserver to the PHP interpreter, the interpreter considers everything outside of <?php ?> to be output. In other words, it's like you just `echo`ed every line of it, but without the extra typing.

Comment: Thank you! I see why what I was trying to do doesn't work. When it echoes the line out it does it only once so when the loop keeps going it isn't echoed again.

Comment: no, if you have some content inside of a loop, it will be output on each iteration of the loop -- see the example I put in the question: it should produce the output you would expect, a line of text for each `$item` in `$items`

Comment: Oh true, thanks again, I'm silly, and couldn't see the invisible </ul> echoed every time. Now I understand exactly what was happening.